# Transpose multiple variables in multiple rows

Tags: r

I have data with multiple rows for every patients (id) due to multiple values for time_1 ang age_1.
I would like to obtain a db with a single row for every patient and traspose time_1 and age_1 values from the other rows to time_2 and time_3 and age_2 and age_3..

My data:

```
  id    ses_cd  hbi sacro   spondilo    time_1  m_s_sacro   age_1
  1 0   0   0   0   126 0   43
  1 0   0   0   0   158 0   45
  1 0   0   0   0   223 0   22
  2 0   0   0   1   140 1   51
  2 0   0   0   1   358 1   98
  2 0   0   0   1   140 1   35
  3 0   0   0   0   75  0   39
  3 0   0   0   0   76  0   75
  3 0   0   0   0   258 0   88
  3 0   0   0   0   856 0   45
  4 0   0   0   0   30  0   31
  4 0   0   0   0   30  0   33
  4 0   0   0   0   30  0   55
  4 0   0   0   0   12  0   65
  5 0   0   0   0   212 0   49
  6 0   0   1   0   10  1   42
  7 1   1   0   0   20  0   19
  8 0   0   0   0   3   0   51
  9 1   1   0   1   8   0   30
  10    1   0   0   0   0   0   34
  11    1   1   0   0   93  0   27
  12    0   0   0   0   5   0   20
  13    1   1   0   0   2   0   61
  14    0   0   0   0   44  0   24
  15    0   0   0   0   0   0   55
  16    0   0   0   0   166 0   42
  17    1   1   0   1   1   1   35
  18    1   0   0   0   1   0   29
  19    0   0   0   0   204 0   60
  20    0   0   0   1   0   0   66
```

I would like to obtain this:
[image]

I've tried this but just for one variable, how can I add a second (and a third maybe)?

```
db %>%
  group_by(id, sacro) %>%
  summarise(time_1 = toString(time_1)) %>%
  separate(time_1, into = paste0("time_1", 1:5), sep = ", ", fill = "right", extra = "drop")
```

I also would like to keep all the variables in db..

Comment: What are you trying to do? explain the logic. And provide the data using `dput(x)`

Comment: @NadPat sorry, I've copied the db in a wrong way